# Testing Spring MVC Router with MockMVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, spring-mvc-test

I'm trying to test my Spring MVC webapp with Spring test. It uses [springmvc-router](https://github.com/resthub/springmvc-router) for routing and that appears to break the tests, which work fine when I use `@RequestMapping` instead of my `routes.conf` file.

I have a `.jsp` file called `valid.jsp`, and it displays fine when I run the development site from Jetty. The controller is:

```
@Controller
@EnableWebMvc
public class AuthController {
  public String valid() {
    return "valid";
  }
}
```

My `routes.conf` file maps `GET /valid   authController.valid`.

Now, my tester looks like

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/test-context.xml",
    "/spring/spring-security.xml",
    "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml"})
@WebAppConfiguration
@Import(RouteConfig.class)
public class AuthControllerTest {
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  @Before
  public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc =
        MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).dispatchOptions(true).build();
  }

  @Test
  public void testValid() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/validation-success"))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
  }
```

When the `mockMvc.perform()` is run, a NullPointerException is thrown:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:64)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:170)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:137)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:141)
    at com.mypackage.AuthControllerTest.testValid(AuthControllerTest.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.resthub.web.springmvc.router.HTTPRequestAdapter.parseRequest(HTTPRequestAdapter.java:196)
    at org.resthub.web.springmvc.router.RouterHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RouterHandlerMapping.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:300)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.getHandler(TestDispatcherServlet.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:916)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
    ... 41 more
```

So the question is: is it possible to use Spring's test framework with springmvc-router?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After doing some digging, I've discovered that the `HTTPRequestAdapter.parseRequest()` method has an issue with the way that MockMVC sends requests. Specifically, the request sent by MockMVC doesn't include a header in the request with the name `host`.

`HTTPRequestAdapter` requires that header and does not account for the fact that it can be null, so it generates the `NullPointerException`.

I fixed the issue with this code:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/validation-success")
       .header("host", "localhost:80"))
       .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

The `host` header won't be null and your tests should pass.